# React - set direction arrow to table headings

Tags: reactjs, lodash, jsx, css-tables

I'm facing a little problem on setting direction arrows when clicking on table headings in order to perform sorting of each column. The table is dynamically created as you can see in the code below.

What I would like to achieve is the arrow to appear only when clicking on each column and disappearing when switching column.
What I've managed to do is to toggle the arrows but it's appearing on all the columns even on page load which is something I don't want.

Do you have any suggestions in order to do it? I feel out of ideas...

Here is the class snippet:

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { orderBy } from "lodash";

class Test extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            currentlyDisplayed: this.props.games,
            sortParams: {
                direction: undefined   
            }
        };

        this.handleColumnHeaderClick = this.handleColumnHeaderClick.bind(this);
    }

    handleColumnHeaderClick(sortKey, e) {
        const {
            currentlyDisplayed,
            sortParams: { direction }
        } = this.state;


        // Check, what direction now should be
        const sortDirection = direction === "desc" ? "asc" : "desc";

        // performing the column switch and class toggle
        this.setState(prevState => ({ editingContactId: prevState.editingContactId === sortKey? null:sortKey})) 
        

        // Sort collection
        const sortedCollection = orderBy(currentlyDisplayed, [sortKey], [sortDirection]);

        //Update component state with new data
        this.setState({
          currentlyDisplayed: sortedCollection,
          sortParams: {
            direction: sortDirection
          }
        });
    }

      
    printObj(type='body', obj) {
        const content = [];

        for(const [key, value] of Object.entries(obj)) {
            content.push(this.buildCell(type, key, value));
        }

        return content;
    }

 
    buildCell(type='body', key, value) {
        return (
            <>       
                { type==='header' ? <th className={key === this.state.editingContactId ? 'sort-desc' : 'sort-asc'}  onClick={(e) => this.handleColumnHeaderClick(key, e)} key={key}>{key}</th> : <td key={key}>{value}</td> }
            </>
        );

    }

    render() {

        return (
            <>
              <table>
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            {this.state.currentlyDisplayed.length !== 0 && 
                                this.printObj('header', this.props.games[0])
                            }
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        {this.state.currentlyDisplayed.length !== 0 && 
                            this.state.currentlyDisplayed.map((obj, key) => {
                                return (
                                    <tr key={key}>
                                        { this.printObj('body', obj) }
                                    </tr>
                                );
                            })
                        }
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </>
        );
    }
}

export default connect(
    mapStateToProps
)(Test);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this using the sort direction.

```
 <th className={key === this.state.editingContactId
  ? this.sortParams.direction === "asc"
    ? "sort-asc"
    : "sort-desc"
  : ""}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. I'm getting the same problem as before. The "this.state.editingContactId" is NULL when I click for the second time on same column or another. Hence no class is assigned the second time. It works only on the first column click. I'm not understand why...any idea?